# How to derive a solution to stochastic difference equation using Blanchard-Kahn method?

Tags: macroeconomics, difference-equations, rbc

Let $z_t =\rho z_{t-1}+\epsilon_t$, where $|\rho|<1$ and $E_t e_{t+1}=0$

I need to solve the stochastic difference equation $E_t[y_{t+2}-2ay_{t+1}+by_t]=z_t$ for
$y_t$, $t\geq0$, where $0<b<1$ and $2a>b+1$

In class, my professor said that when you face this kind of SDE, you can define a new variable and use Blanchard-Kahn method to get a solution. He even gave me a hint that the solution $y_t$ should look like $y_t = \delta y_{t-1}+\gamma z_t$, where $\delta, \gamma$ are some functions of the parameters.

First, using the hint, I tried to change $y_{t+2}=\delta y_{t+1}+\gamma z_{t+2} = \delta y_{t+1}+\gamma\rho z_{t+1}+\epsilon_{t+1}$. So, I changed the SDE to this one.

> $E_t[\delta y_{t+1}+\gamma\rho z_{t+1}+\epsilon_{t+1}-2ay_{t+1}+by_t]=(\delta-2a)E_ty_{t+1} +by_t+\gamma \rho E_t z_{t+1} = z_t$

With this and the given equation on $z$, $E_tz_{t+1} =\rho z_{t}$, I tried to solve it using Blanchard-Kaehn method.

However, I couldn't get the solution since I don't know exact the range of $\delta$ (I'm not sure even if my approach was correct)

Could you please tell me how to solve this problem? I don't know even how to start solving this one..

Comment: Hi: I can't answer your question or help you but I can say that I reached into this literature a few years back and never found it very clear. In fact, I found it extremely difficult because it seemed like you always had to understand the whole literature in order to understand one piece of it. But  here's something that I didn't find in my past investigations that seems more  readable than average. pages 50-70  look particularly relevant to your problem. https://www.mv.helsinki.fi/home/ajripatt/opetus/metrics/slides.pdf

Comment: This looks possibly helpful also.  http://web.sgh.waw.pl/~jg23234/do/EMiDO%20-%20wyk03%20-%20Blanchard%20Kahn.pdf

Comment: One more for the road. http://www.sef.hku.hk/~yluo/teaching/econ6012/2013topic5ii.pdf

Comment: @markleeds thank you! But I actually reviewed the materials you gave before asking the question, and still did not understand..

Comment: I wish that I could help you. Maybe ask your professor if he knows of a good reference for this topic. I never really found  a good one that illustrated the various methods ( blanchard-kahn, uhlig, sargent, sims ) with examples.

Comment: I hope that you didn't find this one earlier because there are some good and hopefully useful examples in it. https://www.academia.edu/30393697/How_to_get_the_Blanchard_Kahn_form_from_a_general_linear_rational_expectations_model

Comment: @markleeds thanks a lot! Your resource is really helpful

Comment: I hope it helps. Like  I said, I've dealt with the "rational expectations" monster before and he's a handful !!!!!!!!  As an aside, Pesaran's "limits to rational expectations" is , IMHO, one of the best books as far as explaining what's going on with RE. But I don't know if it has a blanchard-khan example in it  ?.